# Как парсить тело POST-запроса в NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Отправляю следующий запрос к серверу:

```
curl --request POST --header "Content-Type: application/json" --data {"username":"xyz","password":"xyz"} https://example.com
```

В NodeJS использую express:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(bodyParser.json())
```

И пытаюсь прочитать тело запроса:

```
console.log(req.body)
```

Вместо строки мне выводится какая-то ахинея:

```
[Object: null prototype] { '{"username":"xyz","password":"xyz"}': '' }
```

И как её прочитать?

Comment: Вам ясно дали понять что вы подставляете вместо имени объект а значение как таковое не  передаете

Comment: man curl. Вам нужен —data-binary

Comment: @sair спасибо, разобрался. Нужно было сделать `--data 'data={"foo": "bar"}'`